# Boolean expressions simplification

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have found these boolean expressions based on a truth table:

1. $(abc'd') + (ab'c'd) + (a'bcd') + (a'b'cd)$

(EDITED for 2))

2. $(abcd') + (abc'd) + (ab'cd) + (ab'c'd') + (a'bcd) + (a'bc'd') + (a'b'c'd) + (a'b'cd')$

However, I need to simplify them. (' for complement, + for or, xy is for x and y)

Comment: Are you allowed to use Karnaugh maps?

Comment: No, we have not learned it in class yet.

Comment: What simplification methods have you been taught?

Comment: @user400188 We have been told to use distributive, associative, commutative laws as well as the 12 basic boolean algebra rules.

Comment: Last question, can you use the $\oplus$ (XOR) operator?

Comment: @user400188 yes

Answer (score 1):

$1. ~~(abc'd')+(ab'c'd) \iff  ac'(bd'+b'd),$ and $(a'bcd')+ (a'b'cd) \iff a'c(bd'+b'd)$, so this yields $(ac'+a'c)(bd'+b'd) \iff (a \oplus c)(b \oplus d)$.

$2.$  Factor as in problem $1$ using $ab'$ and $a'b$, and then $ab$ and $a'b'$, and you'll end up with $(a \oplus b) \oplus (c \oplus d)$.

Comment: @anonymouseeeee Still not sure it's right.  Three terms start with $ab$ and only one starts with $a'b'$.  That could be what's intended but I suspect more symmetry was meant.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. There was a mistake in my truth table. I have fixed it once more.

Comment: @anonymouseeeee  The symmetry leads to a nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using $\oplus$ to denote the XOR operation.

For the first one:

\begin{align}
&(ab{c'}d') + ({a}b'{c'}d) + ({a'}b{c}d') + ({a'}b'{c}d)&\\\
&{ac'}{(bd'+b'd)}+{a'c}{(bd'+b'd)}&\text{Factor}\\
&ac'{(b\oplus d)}+a'c{(b\oplus d)}&\text{Use }\oplus\\
& {(b\oplus d)}(ac'+a'c)&\text{Factor}\\
&(b\oplus d)(a\oplus c)&\text{Use }\oplus
\end{align}

For the second one:

\begin{align}&{
(abcd') + (abc'd) + (ab'cd) + (ab'c'd') + (a'bcd) + (a'bc'd') + (a'b'c'd) + (a'b'cd')}&\\
&{ab(cd'+c'd)+cd(ab'+a'b)+a'b'(cd'+c'd)+c'd'(ab'+a'b)}&\text{Factor}\\
&{ab(c\oplus d)+cd(a\oplus b)+a'b'(c\oplus d)+c'd'(a\oplus b)}&\text{Use }\oplus\\
&{(c\oplus d)(ab+a'b')+(a\oplus b)(cd+c'd')}&\text{Factor}\\
&{(c\oplus d)(a\oplus b)'+(a\oplus b)(c\oplus d)'}&\text{Use }\oplus\\
&{(c\oplus d)\oplus(a\oplus b)}&\text{Use }\oplus
\end{align}